# Twilio help get callerId to display To in php

Tags: php, xml, twilio, twilio-php

I am trying to get the callerid to display To in the xml for the caller id as you can see. How can i do that? What am I doing wrong? I cant seem to get everything right. I need some help I am not that good at coding and I have looked up on the internet how to get most of the stuff but im not able to get my code working. Thanks in advance!

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> <TwilioResponse><Call><To>+12017447179</To><ToFormatted>(201) 744-7179</ToFormatted><From>+16463621515</From><FromFormatted>(646) 362-1515</FromFormatted><PhoneNumberSid/><Status>queued</Status><StartTime/><EndTime/><Duration/><Price/><PriceUnit>USD</PriceUnit><Direction>outbound-api</Direction><AnsweredBy/><ApiVersion>2010-04-01</ApiVersion><Annotation/><ForwardedFrom/><GroupSid/><CallerName/></Call></TwilioResponse>


http://gordonbusiness.com/vb_menu.xml


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
<Gather action="="/forward_call.php" numDigits="1">
<Play loop="2">https://gordonbusiness.com/studentloan.mp3</Play>
</Gather>
<Say>Sorry, I didn't get your response.</Say>
<Redirect>vb_menu.xml</Redirect>
</Response>

http://gordonbusiness.com/forward_call.php -

Response sent to 2nd URL:
1   $user_pushed = (int) $_REQUEST['Digits'];


<?php
header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
echo '<Response>';
# @start snippet$
user_pushed = (int) $_REQUEST['Digits'];
# @end snippet
$string_data = "<TwilioResponse>";
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string_data);
$phonenumber == (string) $xml->To;
if ($user_pushed == 1)
{
echo '<Dial callerId=$phonenumber>
<Number>+18552426127</Number>
</Dial>';
}
else if ($user_pushed == 9)
{
echo '<Hangup />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I think you have most of this right, the bit that is missing is getting the number that was dialled as the caller ID.

You seem to be building the To number out of some anonymous XML structure that you create. You can get the To number from the request parameters. Much like you got the `Digits` parameter.

So, instead of

```
$string_data = "<TwilioResponse>";
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string_data);
$phonenumber == (string) $xml->To;
```

You could just set `$phonenumber` like:

```
$phonenumber = $_REQUEST["To"];
```

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: it is getting closer but it still isnt right. was giving me a five digit code now its giving me a 8 digit caller id.

Comment: <TwilioResponse> sends the <To> and <From> to the xml file i need to get it from the xml file to the caller id. When i dont put anything in there it comes up as the twilio number.

Comment: Oh, do you need to use `$_REQUEST["From"]` then? Or am I getting the question wrong entirely?

Comment: u had it right the first time we are trying to get the To from the .xml and display it as the callerId.